# Trouble with importing a CSV with ws.QueryTables.Add

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

Im having trouble importing a csv file. The first row works fine, but the rest are all wonky. Here is a sample of the first and second row from the csv:

```
"Order # ","Purchased From (Store)","Purchased On","Bill to Name","Ship to Name","G.T. (Base)","G.T. (Purchased)",Status
202366,"RaD.com
Ra D
Ra D Default View
","Dec 26, 2015 12:07:25 PM","John Smith","John Smith",$70.00,$70.00,Pending
```

The order number goes into the correct cell, but it splits the RaD.com Ra D and Ra D Default View onto different rows in different cells. The date also gets cut into two cells as [,Dec 19][ 2015 12:07:25 PM"]

Heres the code I'm using.

```
Sub ImportCSV(fname)
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
ws.Name = "temp" & Worksheets.Count + 1


With ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="TEXT;" & fname, _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "Temp" & Worksheets.Count + 1
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    '.UseListObject = False
End With
End Sub
```

The RaD.com cell doesn't have to be formatted perfectly, it just all needs to be in one cell. I cant change the way the text file is formatted because there are thousands of them.

Comment: IIRC, the CSV format does not permit line breaks in cell values, even when quoted. Line break as the row terminator always overrides column terminators and quotes.

Comment: Weird, its definitely got some formatting. When I open the document in excel manually it works fin, but when I import it using this method it doesn't. Just checked the file type and confirmed it is a csv.

Comment: Wait, why are you opening it as a QueryTable?  Open it as a workbook, then copy the worksheet into your current workbook, then define a QueryTable over it.

Comment: The queryTable was the only thing I could figure out. How would I do that? I really just need the data copied over into the current workbook

Comment: Just open it as a workbook then. I think its Application.Workbooks.Open.

Comment: So I'll just change the importCSV(fname) sub to `Application.Workbooks.Open(fname) ` then I need to figure out how to copy and paste the information into the other workbook and then close out the one it opened.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your csv file, and everything is correct. Only the field `"Purchased From (Store)"` is multiline (which is allowed if correctly quoted, which is the case here).

So you need a parameter like `.TextFile`multiline or something. I'll see if I can find one.

The date shouldn't get cut, because it's properly quoted as well:

```
"Dec 26, 2015 12:07:25 PM"
```

...

Looked up the parameters for QueryTable, and can't find one for multiline.. strange.

But you might have to set the [QueryType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213498.aspx) to `xlTextImport`. Otherwise, you'll have to use another method. But multiline csv is certainly valid and any decent csv parser shouldn't have a problem with that.

> So it can be multline as long as its in a cell?

Yes, if properly quoted:

```
field1, "field
2
more data
end field2", rest of fields
```

If you really need to do it with QueryTable, you might try to use an ODBC connection string instead of `Connection:="TEXT;"`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx).

Comment: So it can be multline as long as its in a cell . Maybe if I fixed that the date would work. When the date gets cut into different cells the first starts with a comma [,Dec 19]. The comma might be coming from the store.

Comment: Yes, csv can be multiline (don't know yet if QueryTables will accept that though - but it should, considering all the other parameters.) - Indeed, as long as multiline isn't fixed, the data that follows will also be parsed wrong - on the last line: "," is seen as a quoted field.